# Registering DirectChannelMetrics as a JMX Bean programmatically

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, spring-integration, jmx

I have a Spring integration application with several `FileTailingMessageProducer`s and `DirectMessageChannel`s created programmatically -- i.e. not through XML configuration, but within a `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`. Now I would like to monitor the message channels using JMX. I guess I will have to add them using my integrationMBeanExporter.

This is what I tried:

```
DirectChannelMetrics directChannelMetrics = new DirectChannelMetrics(tailedLines, "tailedLines");
integrationMBeanExporter.getServer().registerMBean(directChannelMetrics, new ObjectName("d:foo=foo"));
```

Yet I am getting the following Exception:

```
javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: MBean class org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions
```

It is surprising to me, that the DirectChannelMetrics does not fulfill JMX requirements, since when I look into my application with jvisualvm I can see other beans of this type registered without problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From one side `MBeanExporter` does this on the matter:

```
return new StandardMBean(bean, ((Class<Object>) ifc));
```

Before registering bean as an `MBean`.

From other side I think your logic smells a bit. It looks abnormal to create `MessageChannel`s at runtime. Especially those which are for the JMX export.

I can agree about dynamic `FileTailingMessageProducer`s, but seems for me we can avoid dynamic channels with refactored logic for the predefined channels.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage Spring's `MBeanExport.registerManagedResource(directChannelMetrics, new ObjectName("d:foo=foo"))`. Spring will generate a management interface for the instance of `DirectChannelMetric` class. But `DirectChannelMetric` class needs either to implement the `Mbean`/`MXBean` interface or to match current `MBeanInfoAssembler` expectations(be marked with the `@ManagedResource` annotation in the case of `MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler` or implements one of  specified interfaces in the case of `InterfaceBasedMBeanInfoAssembler` etc).